# Having Trouble Writing Image Files with Python

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, gdal

I am having a bit of trouble with writing image files to a folder on my PC. 
As you can see in my script below, I have used os.path.expanduser because I intend to use send this script to another computer that will obviously not have the same filepath as my local pc. When I run this script, the gdal_calc runs properly, however, there is no output? Any ideas on how I could create an output file or what may be causing the image to disappear would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import sys
import os


# Set constants
# The pathway to the image files are nested within the '--outfile=' command

inHVFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Zeros\\ZerosHV-Test-3.img')
outPlacement = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\newHVZeros.img')
outVFile = '--outfile=outPlacement'
outVFile_1 = '--outfile=outPlacement_1'
inVHFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Zeros\\ZerosVH-Test-3.img')
outPlacement_1 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\newVHZeros.img')



subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inHVFile, outVFile, '--calc=A+1'])

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inVHFile, outVFile_1, '--calc=A+1'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few problems with your script. I have annotated them below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^  THIS ISN'T A BASH SCRIPT, THE ENVIRONMENT IS PYTHON

import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import sys
import os


# Set constants
# The pathway to the image files are nested within the '--outfile=' command
# YOU CANNOT NEST A VARIABLE INSIDE A STRING LIKE YOU ARE TRYING TO DO

inHVFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Zeros\\ZerosHV-Test-3.img')
outPlacement = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\newHVZeros.img')
outVFile = '--outfile=outPlacement'
#                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ THIS WILL NOT EXPAND TO YOUR outPlacement VARIABLE
outVFile_1 = '--outfile=outPlacement_1'
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ THIS WILL NOT EXPAND TO YOUR outPlacement_1 VARIABLE
inVHFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Zeros\\ZerosVH-Test-3.img')
outPlacement_1 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\newVHZeros.img')



subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inHVFile, outVFile, '--calc=A+1']) 
# This call to gdal_calc.py will produce a file called "outPlacement.tif" in whatever directory the script is run

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inVHFile, outVFile_1, '--calc=A+1'])
# This call to gdal_calc.py will produce a file called "outPlacement_1.tif" in whatever directory the script is run
```

Here is a correct version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys
import os

# Set constants
inHVFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Zeros\\ZerosHV-Test-3.img')
outPlacement = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\newHVZeros.img')
outVFile = '--outfile=' + outPlacement

inVHFile = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Zeros\\ZerosVH-Test-3.img')
outPlacement_1 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\newVHZeros.img')
outVFile_1 = '--outfile=' + outPlacement_1

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inHVFile, outVFile, '--calc=A+1'])
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py','-A', inVHFile, outVFile_1, '--calc=A+1'])
```